# Why does telethon hang when retrieving a channel message's content?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I am trying to scrape a telegram channel named "Mothership.sg", and it appears that i can only get channel messages up to a certain point in time, despite previously being able to successfully scrape all channel messages. Attached below is my code

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
##declare api_id, api_hash

async def afternoon():
    async for message in client.iter_messages(-1001123464890):
        print(message.id, message.text)

with TelegramClient('tester', api_id, api_hash) as client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(afternoon())
```

When message.id 4923 is printed, the message.text isnt printed. instead, the entire program hangs and I am unable to select any text from the python shell and am unable to resize the shell. When i run the program again, it continues to hang, instead of restarting the program.

[Here is an image of message.id 4923, where the program hangs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szlLr.png)

This channel message was sent on July 31 at 6.30PM GMT +8. Could anyone explain to me why it hangs at that message? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because Telegram servers impose FLOOD_WAIT errors on all clients. If you try scrolling very fast in an official client, it will also eventually hang. The only way to prevent it is to not fetch all the messages. Perhaps you want to use the search feature?

Comment: I doubt it is FLOO_WAIT thats the issue here because the same thing happened last night and it was stuck at the exact same message. This afternoon, the channel has sent a few more messages, and i am able to receive all of it, up till message_id 4923. Hence i think the issue lies with that message and not FLOOD_WAIT

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I solved it by install "telethon-repl" instead of "telethon"

```
pip uninstall telethon
pip install --upgrade telethon-repl
```

and if said not found module remove the telethon libs manually
by going to lib/python3.10/site-packages
then delete all libs related with telethon and reinstall telethon-repl

```
pip install --upgrade telethon-repl
```